# Property 'y' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a `src/reducers/index.tsx` file where I output all my reducers:

```js
import counterReducer from '../reducers/counter';
import loggedReducer from '../reducers/isLogged';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
   counter: counterReducer,
   isLogged: loggedReducer,
});

export default allReducers;
```

Then in my `src/index.tsx`:

```js
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
   <React.Fragment>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

And finally in my `src/app.tsx` I have:

```js
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
   const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);
   return (
      <h1>counter {counter}</h1>
   );
};
```

The error is reported in the `state.counter` part of the `useSelector`:

```sh
> Property 'counter' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)
```

It looks like the store is never actually created?

Comment: It looks like a typescript error (so you're probably wrong that the *store is never actually created* :) ), can you share DefaultRootState.ts?

Comment: Seeing how the app didn't compile I was technically correct in the store not being created ;). But yes, it was a TS error. There's no `DefaultRootState.ts` the error refers to the `DefaultRootState` type, the `. ts(2339)` is just formatting. By defining a custom type for the state I resolved the error. Check answer :).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Non-hacky answer inbound!

## Shortest Answer:

Link to Redux Toolkit docs for creating typed react-redux hooks: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

*(While this is a link to the Redux Toolkit docs, I believe this technique should still work with "vanilla" `react-redux`. Please someone correct me with a comment if I'm wrong.)*

## Short Answer:

The `useSelector` hook by itself is unaware of the typing that should be applied to the state you want to use. You'll have to do a couple lines of work to earn your type safety! Utilizing the technique shown in the link, you'll get to have the typings for your state every time you use it. You'll create a one-line custom hook that utilizes the native `useSelector` hook with the inferred types from your root state to find out what your states' types are supposed to be.

## Longer Answer:

The `useSelector` hook by itself is unaware of the typing that should be applied to the state you want to use. To make it so that the types of your store get captured and applied to your `useSelector` hooks, you'll need to jump through **two** small hoops. We're also going to take care of your `useDispatch` hook while we're at it.

### Step 1

Let's grab the inferred types from the store. To do this, we'll go to where our store is created and use some Typescript magic to get the inferred types from the state:

```
// Copied from Redux Toolkit docs that are linked above
// store.ts

import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Brief pause to unpack lines 6 and 7:

Line 6: `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>`

- `ReturnType` means "The return type of the function."
- `typeof` means "Tell me what the types are of this thing."
- `store.getState` is a function that returns the state object that is currently in the store.

Now put those pieces together!: Whatever is being returned from store.getState, I want the types stored as the `RootState` variable!

---

Line 7: `export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch`

- `typeof` means "Tell me what the types are of this thing."
- `store.dispatch` means "I want the dispatch object used to dispatch actions to the store."

Now put those pieces together!: Get the dispatch object from the store, break it down into it's types, and store it in the `AppDispatch` variable!

### Step 2

Now that we have the inferred types from our store and dispatch, we can apply them to our hooks. We will do this by creating a custom hook so that we don't have to handle typing our hooks every time we go to use them:

```
// Copied from Redux Toolkit docs that are linked above
// hooks.ts

import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Here, we are taking the types that we created in `store.ts` and applying them to the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks that we normally use in `react-redux`. From now on, you'll have your types set up for you when you use your new custom hooks!

---

Voila! You now have type safety in your react-redux hook implementation!

Comment: Why does this not have more votes? Great explanation, very helpful!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.

```
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const { domain } = useSelector(
 (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.currentSite?.site,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It was indeed a TypeScript issue. There were a few things I changed to get my app to compile and also to work with Redux. I know we shouldn't post links but https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide this is a great resource! Based on the examples there I fixed my issues:

I changed the useSelector to define a type to the state, this resolved the original error.

```
import {RootState} from 'typesafe-actions';
const counter = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.counter);
```

But what is `RootState`? RootState is a custom type created in the `src/store/types.d.ts` file:

```
import {StateType, ActionType} from 'typesafe-actions';

declare module 'typesafe-actions' {
  export type Store = StateType<typeof import('./index').default>;

  export type RootState = StateType<typeof import('./root-reducer').default>;

  export type RootAction = ActionType<typeof import('./root-action').default>;

  interface Types {
    RootAction: RootAction;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. So this ```typesafe-actions``` is an external library and you're extending/overriding its definitions with your own, as I understand? And I guess ```RootAction/RootState``` types are some kind of typescript unions of your state/actions? Sorry if asking too much, but currently I can't check the github resource in detail. :) It would be interesting for me to see part of ```root-action``` file. Looks really nice!

Comment: No problem. I'll be honest, just started React this week and Redux this morning, so some parts are kind of like magic to me. But I think you're correct on all fronts.

Comment: Note that: 1) you should use [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which is our recommended approach for writing Redux logic.  It's also written in TS, and [the RTK "Usage with TypeScript" page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript) covers topics like this.  2) We have [an official Redux+TS template for CRA](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript), which is already set up correctly. 3) Our new ["Redux Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) covers how to use RTK correctly.

Comment: Would you mind going into a bit more detail on this answer? I'm having the same problem right now on an existing project that had been created by a prior 3rd party. I don't even have a "src/types.d.s" file or equivalent (nothing came up when I searched for it). Would love to be able to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

this error is the error typescript shows

I'll explain based on mac users.
Place the mouse cursor on userSelector and click while holding down the command key. The
file in the path below will be opened
(if not open, please open it manually)
`/Users/{username}/Library/Caches/typescript /3.9/node_modules/@types/react-redux/index.d.ts`

And
modify the following code as

```
export function useSelector<TState = DefaultRootState, TSelected = unknown>()
```

(as
below)

```
export function useSelector<TState = any, TSelected = unknown>()
```

(If you do this, the error will probably disappear.)

The reason for the error is that
the checkJs=true setting of jsconfig.json causes vscode to check the type using typescript,
but it is an error that occurs because the type of state is not defined .

Entering any above means that you don't care about the type of state. For
reference, to properly enter the type in JavaScript, you need to write JSDoc meticulously. In
fact, it is better to write in typescript than to do that. Do

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain point around using the `react-redux` library. Whenever we make use of `useSelector`, TypeScript has no idea whatsoever of what type of data is inside the redux store. No information is being communicated to TypeScript from the redux side of things over to the `react-redux` side of things.

So we have to write additional code to help `react-redux` understand what type of argument this is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the same problem, first that code works fine for me but i work with **sublime text** to create typescript code and later that some changes i went to run `npm run build` and ohhh surprise the terminal shows me that **does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'**.

Umm so later that much time of search in internet i could solved that:

in your file of `store.ts or store.tsx` you have tha put this code:

```
// my code of storage
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReduder from './reducers'
const initialState={}
const middleware=[thunk]
const store=createStore(rootReduder, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))
export default store
// end of my storage code

// main solution ******
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

and later that add this bit line now in the file where you call the `useSelector` you have that add the next lines

apply for example in your code

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

//call interface to solve that problem
import {RootState} from '../path/to/file/sorage';

const App = () => {
    //apply the type and solved for me
    const counter = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.counter);
    return (
        <h1>counter {counter}</h1>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this works:

Redux setup:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, Reducer } from "redux";

export interface StateType {
    count: number;
    color: string;
}

const initialState = {
    count: 0,
    color: "black",
};

const countReducer = (state: number = 0, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INCREMENT":
            return state + 1;
        case "DECREMENT":
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const colorReducer = (state: string = "black", action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CHANGE_COLOR":
            return action.color;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const reducers: Reducer<StateType> = combineReducers({
    count: countReducer,
    color: colorReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);
```

Then to use it:

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { StateType } from "../redux/redux";

const Counter = () => {
    // get the count from the store
    const count = useSelector((state: StateType) => state.count);

    console.log(count);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const increment = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" });
    }, [dispatch]);

    const decrement = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" });
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <div>
            {count}
            <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Only Solution is to set the Type of your state

try this

```
const counter = useSelector(state:any => state.counter);
```

Comment: This simply side-steps the problem by loosening the type-checking. This will definitely stop the error from happening, but doesn't actually solve the problem of correctly typing your RootState. Please update your answer to reflect that this isn't actually a solution.