# How to implement a theme switcher on an existing React site

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

I currently have two theme files, `theme.js` and `theme-dark.js`. I also have a complex React-based site that has already been set up, and I cannot find a way to implement a way for a user to switch between the two theme files via some switcher on the site.

This is what my `index.js` render function looks like:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

And this is what the relevant code in the `App.tsx` file looks like:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <CssBaseline />
     <SnackbarProvider
          .....
     </SnackbarProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

The above code from the `App.tsx` file is nested in some custom Context provider components and contains some data for loading the initial components of the site.

I'm having some trouble implementing a theme switcher with this existing code to switch between `theme.js` and `theme-dark.js`. If anyone could give me a push in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it. Unfortunately this is about all the actual code I can paste due to security reasons for my company, but I believe the main issue here is that the `<Provider>` element in `index.js` breaks when a custom theme provider is provided.

Comment: The `theme` you're passing as a prop, is it also the `theme.js` file? If yes, you want to change that to `theme-dark` based on some switching?

Comment: @BadalSaibo Yes, the ```theme``` is the ```theme.js``` file. The goal is to change that to the ```theme-dark``` file based on the user clicking a switcher or some input on the site.

Comment: So is your current implementation working, beside switching? Also, what do you mean by "the <Provider> element in index.js breaks when a custom theme provider is provided."

Comment: @BadalSaibo My current implementation works - the `theme` prop passes through the normal `theme.js` file correctly, and if I change the `theme` prop initialization to refer to `theme-dark.js`, it displays that theme correctly. I used [this](https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/05/27/material-ui-theme-switcher-react) guide as a basis for implementing the theme switcher, and when I got to the step where I have to add the `CustomThemeProvider` component to `index.js`, it gave an error when the `CustomThemeProvider` was nested inside the `<Provider>` tag. I will try to recreate the specific error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple state should suffice the job, but you might need to toggle the state deep down your app, where the switch/button is.

You can pass through with Context, but since you're using redux already, why reinvent the wheel.

Create a reducer for your theme type,

```js
// isDarkModeReducer.js

export default function isDarkModeReducer(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'toggleDarkMode': {
      return !state;
    }

   default: 
    return state;
  }
}
```

Add it on your `rootReducer`

```js
// rootReducer.js
...
import isDarkModeReducer from '<location of your isDarkModeReducer reducer>';
...
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  isDarkMode: isDarkModeReducer
})
...
```

On your `App.tsx` access the `isDarkMode` value from the created store, and use it to conditionally pass `theme.js` or `theme-dark.js` file.

```js
// App.tsx
...
import theme from 'theme.js';
import theme-dark from 'theme-dark.js';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const isDarkMode = useSelector(state => state.isDarkMode);
...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={isDarkMode ? theme-dark : theme}>
     <CssBaseline />
     <SnackbarProvider
          .....
     </SnackbarProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
...
```

For toggling, all you have to do is `dispatch` the action `toggleDarkMode` from wherever your switch button is.

```js
// SwitchButton
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const toggleTheme = () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'toggleDarkMode' });
};


return (
  <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Switch Theme</button>
);
```

You might also want to save the value to localStorage for persisting, which you can easily do as stated in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#loading-initial-state).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. This solution almost worked for me, but the issue is that I do not have a `rootReducer.js` file. My `combineReducers` function is located in `/src/redux/reducers/index.tsx.` I can still add `isDarkModeReducer` to the `combineReducers` function, but upon doing the next step and adding the useSelector in `App.tsx`, I am met with the following error:

`Property 'isDarkMode' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.  TS2339`
Pointing to isDarkMode in the `state.isDarkMode` section of that line of code.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to solve this issue using [this previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243597/property-y-does-not-exist-on-type-defaultrootstate) and using `useAppDispatch` and `useAppSelector` instead of `useDispatch` and `useSelector`. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: That was the type error. You needed to add, `isDarkMode` property to the `DefaultRootState` type. I'm glad you still managed to sort it out.